# Can I use NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName with TTTAttributedLabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring, tttattritubedlabel

I've tried to use `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` with `TTTAttributedLabel` but it seems to have no effect. For example, this does not seem to do anything:

```
[label setText:text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
     [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:@5.0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length] - 5)];

     return mutableAttributedString;
}];
```

If this attribute is not supported, is there another way to adjust the label baseline?